# Docker container can not resolve .test domain running on localhost

Tags: docker, magento

I have magento running in a docker container using this tutorial (https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento).

The docker container is accessed via https://magento.test and this works fine in the browser. We have a script in magento that is trying to connect to https://magento.test from within the container but this fails with `Could not resolve host: magento.test`.

Basically the host can access magento.test and connect to the docker container. But the docker container can not connect to itself.

I have tried adding extra hosts to the docker-composer.yml (see below) but this has not worked. I am guessing the IP `127.0.0.1` is incorrect.

```
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    image: markoshust/magento-nginx:1.18-8
    ports:
      - "80:8000"
      - "443:8443"
    volumes: &appvolumes
      - ~/.composer:/var/www/.composer:cached
      - ~/.ssh/id_rsa:/var/www/.ssh/id_rsa:cached
      - ~/.ssh/known_hosts:/var/www/.ssh/known_hosts:cached
      - appdata:/var/www/html
      - sockdata:/sock
      - ssldata:/etc/nginx/certs
    extra_hosts: &appextrahosts
      ## Selenium support, replace "magento.test" with URL of your site
      - "magento.test:127.0.0.1"

  phpfpm:
    image: markoshust/magento-php:7.4-fpm-15
    volumes: *appvolumes
    env_file: env/phpfpm.env
    #extra_hosts: *appextrahosts

  db:
    image: mariadb:10.4
    command:
      --max_allowed_packet=64M
      --optimizer_use_condition_selectivity=1
      --optimizer_switch="rowid_filter=off"
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    env_file: env/db.env
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql

  redis:
    image: redis:6.2-alpine
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"

  elasticsearch:
    image: markoshust/magento-elasticsearch:7.16-0
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    environment:
      - "discovery.type=single-node"
      ## Set custom heap size to avoid memory errors
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1g -Xmx1g"
      ## Avoid test failures due to small disks
      ## More info at https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento/issues/488
      - "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.threshold_enabled=false"
      - "index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete"

  rabbitmq:
    image: markoshust/magento-rabbitmq:3.9-0
    ports:
      - "15672:15672"
      - "5672:5672"
    volumes:
      - rabbitmqdata:/var/lib/rabbitmq
    env_file: env/rabbitmq.env

  mailcatcher:
    image: sj26/mailcatcher
    ports:
      - "1080:1080"

  ## Blackfire support, uncomment to enable
  #blackfire:
  #  image: blackfire/blackfire:2
  #  ports:
  #    - "8307"
  #  env_file: env/blackfire.env

  ## Selenium support, uncomment to enable
  #selenium:
  #  image: selenium/standalone-chrome-debug:3.8.1
  #  ports:
  #    - "5900:5900"
  #  extra_hosts: *appextrahosts

volumes:
  appdata:
  dbdata:
  rabbitmqdata:
  sockdata:
  ssldata:
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Does host network usage solve your problem?

```js
services:
  app:
    image: markoshust/magento-nginx:1.18-8
    network_mode: "host"  # share host network
    ports:
      - "80:8000"
      - "443:8443"
    volumes: &appvolumes
      - ~/.composer:/var/www/.composer:cached
      - ~/.ssh/id_rsa:/var/www/.ssh/id_rsa:cached
      - ~/.ssh/known_hosts:/var/www/.ssh/known_hosts:cached
      - appdata:/var/www/html
      - sockdata:/sock
      - ssldata:/etc/nginx/certs
    extra_hosts: &appextrahosts
      ## Selenium support, replace "magento.test" with URL of your site
      - "magento.test:127.0.0.1"
```

Comment: @TornnikeSkhulukhia I have tried adding ```network_more: "host"``` but now my app container won't start :(

Comment: What is the error? I think also ports may be needed to be changed in some other services that you have in docker compose like 80 and 443.

Comment: @TornnikeSkhulukhia Sorry I have added my full docker-composer.yml. The error was `2022/10/19 13:01:59 [emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "phpfpm" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:24

nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "phpfpm" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:24`